# Why Is Cloud Run Failing When I Use Optionals In Express?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

Can someone let me know why I can run express locally fine with parameters such as:

```
 account.setting?.amount
```

But when I try to deploy the same express service to cloud run I get the following error:

> DEFAULT 2023-01-03T04:45:46.367770Z > my-api-v2@1.0.0 start /usr/src/app
> DEFAULT 2023-01-03T04:45:46.367798Z > node app.js
> DEFAULT 2023-01-03T04:45:46.684797Z accountAmount: parseInt((account.setting?.amount ? account.setting?.amount : 0)),
> DEFAULT 2023-01-03T04:45:46.684807Z ^
> ERROR 2023-01-03T04:45:46.684845Z SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.' at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16) at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27) at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10) at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32) at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14) at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19) at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)

It seems that when I take the question mark out the build runs fine but when I use the question mark to define optional parameters the build fails. Is there anything I can do? Also I am using node 16 in my package.json and my cloud build yaml. Here are the scripts:

package.json

```
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16.0.0"
  },
```

cloudbuild.yaml

```
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    dir: 'api'
    args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/my-api-v2', '.', '-t', 'node16']
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: ['push', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/my-api-v2']
  - name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
    entrypoint: gcloud
    args: ['run', 'deploy', 'my-api-v2', '--image', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/my-api-v2', '--region', 'us-central1']
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Does it work locally? Your code, but also the container?

Comment: Yes, I am running it inside of a docker instance using Cloud Code for WebStorm and it works perfect. Im thinking it is the version of Node that Cloud Run is running, but Im not sure how to specify the version of node I want inside of my Cloud Build file. As you can see Im pointing to node 16+ in my package.json.

Comment: Cloud Run runs container, and not NodeJS versions. The nodeJS version is this one you defined in your Dockerfile, and it's the same whatever the runtime environment. However, the gen1 is a sandboxed runtime environment. Can you try to use the 2nd gen execution runtime environment?https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/execution-environments

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I noticed this later on and can’t believe I missed it. Thanks. You can leave this as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @Joe Alvini I have posted the answer as [community wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki) please consider accepting or upvoting:) so that others who are facing the similar issue could spot the workaround easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering this as community wiki.As mentioned above in comments

Cloud Run runs container, and not NodeJS versions. The nodeJS version is this one you defined in your Dockerfile, and it's the same whatever the runtime environment. However, the gen1 is a sandboxed runtime environment. Try to use the 2nd gen [execution runtime environment](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/execution-environments)